# Flutter Web Email Attachment as PDF

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-web, attachment

Can Someone please help me out regarding Email Attachment in flutter Web. I have already done this thing easily in the Android Using the path_provider to first store it in the Temp Directory and then getting the path to share it on the email or anywhere. But Unfortunately path_provider doesn't support in web. So I want that same thing in flutter web. My PDF file is converted into Bytes. How can I Attach that file with the Email in windows or Mac using Flutter Web.

I have Tried share_plus and path_provider in web but path_provider doesn't support in web similarly dart:io.

Comment: Faizan Ali do you find any solution or workaround for this problem?

Comment: Not yet, I left that thing and shared the URL instead.